# How to use the /setblock command in minecraft to make a dispenser face west?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make an automated nether portal maker but I need a dispenser to face west (or any other direction that is not down) Here are some pictures of my problem:
With the regular /setblock command
[image: With the regular /setblock command]

What it should look like: (I did this manually)
[image: What it should look like: (I did this manually)]

So can anyone help me? That would be amazing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `/setblock`, you specify a block's state right after its ID. You can see a block's states if you hover over it with <kbd>F3</kbd> up:

[image: F3 states]

So, to make the dispenser face west:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ dispenser facing=west
```

If you are still on 1.10 or lower, you will instead need to use numeric data values, for which facing west is `4`:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ dispenser 4
```